# How to create wordpress plugin - quote of the day - quote from external website

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I would like to create wordpress plugin that will display "quote of the day". 
I have an external website that hosts a lot of quotes and I would like to use them in my wordpress quote plugin.

I was told that wordpress doesn't allow you to use iframe. 
The random Wordpress quotes plugins I have seen so far are just displaying manually inserted quotes not quotes from some external websites.

Edit: My website is using asp.net and there is a rss feed there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would parse the RSS feed of the quote website (assuming that it has one) and display the quotes that way. You should abe able to use WordPress' native RSS support to do this. Check out an article on it [here](http://www.darrenhoyt.com/2008/01/29/publishing-external-rss-headlines-to-your-wordpress-site/).

Answer (score 1):

The Wordpress site has a good [Plugin Guide](http://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin) that will explain the basics, and provides links to other example/tutorial sites.

To gather the "quote of the day", you've got a couple of options.  First and easiest would be to grab the quote via their RSS feed if available.  Then, a simple script would allow you to place it where you'd like.

If the site doesn't provide an RSS feed, you'll need to implement some sort of screen scraping script to grab the relevant portion of the page you want.  You didn't mention what language you'd like to use, but there are plenty of screen scrapers out for many different languages.

- [Beautiful Soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) works great for Python
- [hpricot](http://wiki.github.com/why/hpricot) works great in Ruby

Answer (score 0):

If you create (or find) some php code that can get the info you need you can create a widget to display it on your site in a widget. You can use widgetifyr.com to wrap the php code in a widget it created for you. Once you create the widget you can use it on your web site just like any other widget.

Answer (score 0):

Quote of the day plugin will first of all need an external source of quotation. That is RSS feed or json or XML source of quotation that will provide new quote everyday.

Next you need to learn widget development for wordpress, reference below will help you getting started.

Finally once you have basic knowledge it will be easy to develop PHP script in wordpress to render quotation that will rotate every day.

For guidance you can look into famous Quote of the day plugins that exist on wordpress plugin repository.

But it won't be recommended to use Quotations from any other website without their permissions.

Below are few good links and tutorials see them they also provides links to other resources and tutorial sites.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin

https://wordpress.org/plugins/quote-of-the-day-itslum/

http://www.darrenhoyt.com/2008/01/29/publishing-external-rss-headlines-to-your-wordpress-site/